# UIBarButtonItem accept only one tap

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have an UIBarButtonItem in my view with the title "Done", when is tapped it creates data in my tableview, the problem is that I need to set it only for one tap, because when its tapped more than once, the data is duplicated, is there a property or method to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you filled up your table by tapping the button, you can disable it.

```
// Assuming the Done button is on the right side of the Navigation Bar
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable once user tapped it for first time. This will prevent user tap next time. Let me know of it helps